# Other than Affine Transformations using Graphics2D

Tags: java, swing, transformation, graphics2d

Using `Graphics2D` object affine transformations can be done. But other than that, can we implement transformations like perspective transformations in a Graphics object so that we can use them in swing components..

There are ways that perspective transformations can be done, but I don't know a way to use them in swing components. Actually what I need here is to use perspective transformations in swing components..

If there is a way to get all the points that Graphics object is going to paint on screen and a way to feed points into a Graphics object, this can be done easily. Any suggestions or better methods..??

Thanks all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, note how [affine and perspective transformations differ](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/413860). In Swing, you can use either of these:

- [`javax.media.jai.PerspectiveTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/PerspectiveTransform.html) from [*Java Advanced Imaging*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/jai-142803.html), for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2500489/230513).
- [`javafx.scene.effect.PerspectiveTransform`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/effect/PerspectiveTransform.html)  in a [`javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html), part of [javafx](/questions/tagged/javafx).

Comment: Can JAI be used in swing..? I never knew.. Can you please tell how..??

Comment: It's creating images and showing..
Thank you for help..!